# TypeError: NAN/INF not supported in write_number() without 'nan_inf_to_errors' Workbook() option

Tags: python, nan, missing-data

I want to save **X** (ndarray) with dimensions (3960, 225) in excel file (.xlsx). In **X** I have some missing values (**nan**). I made a code for it. However, I am getting the error.

Here is the Code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row = 0
    for col, data in enumerate(X):
        worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
    workbook.close()
     df = pd.DataFrame(X)
## save to xlsx file
     filepath = 'my_excel_file.xlsx'
      df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

**Here is the traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Extra_Sensory_Experimetns/main.py", line 475, in <module>
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 69, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 1164, in write_column
    error = self._write(row, col, token, cell_format)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 481, in _write
    return self._write_number(row, col, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Nafees Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 589, in _write_number
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: NAN/INF not supported in write_number() without 'nan_inf_to_errors' Workbook() option
```

Perhaps, it is coming due to nan (missing) values. Is there any simple way to handle this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filling `NaN` values with zero, does not solve the problem, If you want to keep `NaN` values as `NaN`, you should skip filling value in like that:

```
row = 0
for col, data in enumerate(X):
    try:
        worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without skipping? I still want to write everything in the column that isn't blank

Comment: @Nick you can change the data type to string (str). Then write to the columns

Answer (score 6):

You can use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method of pandas.

`df.fillna(0)` will replace all `NaN` with `0.0`

Answer (score 5):

The question has been marked as answered, but since this is currently the top search result for this error message (even before the [xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html)), here is the proper way to deal with it:

Option 1: If you want these values to show up in Excel as errors like `#NUM!`, you can enable this setting when you create the workbook:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path, {"nan_inf_to_errors": True})
```

Option 2: If you want to selectively replace `NaN` (or any other value, for that matter) while filling in data, you can add a handler to the workbook:

```
def replace_nan(worksheet, row, col, value, format=None):
    if math.isnan(value):
        return worksheet.write_blank(row, col, None, format)
    else:
        return None  # let xlsxwriter do its thing

worksheet.add_write_handler(float, replace_nan)
```

The other answers are unsatisfactory, because they either address pandas (which didn't produce the error, OP's program didn't even get that far), or skip the whole row, or replace `NaN` values with 0 (which isn't really correct), or recommend replacing all numbers with strings (which is even worse).

Answer (score 1):

I filled non by using the following code:

```
X[np.isnan(X)] = 0.;
```

Answer (score 0):

Filling NaN values with None is a better option than 0 if you want to keep those cells blank in Excel.

```
df.replace(np.nan, None)
```

Comment: For pandas versions < 1.4.0, you would need to use `df.replace({np.nan: None})` for this kind of replacement operation.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is replace all NaN values with None.

```
df = df.where(df.notnull(), None)
```